dotenv not working in global installed dart package
I have the package dotenv installed in my dart cli project, It seems to work just fine with DotEnv()..load() and running the bin dart file with dart run bin/my_cli.dart. But once I activate my package with dart pub global activate it stops working and it can't find the env file.
When I take a look at my .pub-cache/global_packages folder, I notice the .env file is not there. How can I include my custom environment variables via a .env file in a globally installed dart cli package then?

Did you install the package using dart pub add dotenv? Just verifying...

No I pasted dotenv: ^4.2.0 under the dependencies section in the pubspec.yaml and ran pub get. It's working just fine. The issue is mostly that the .env file is not bundled (or seems not) in the globally activated package. It works just fine running the bin file directly.

What you're doing is very interesting; I hope I can learn more about it and know its sole purpose.

When you say "activate my package with pub global activate", what command are you running exactly? If you don't pass the --overwrite flag and the executable already exists, it won't update the global executable. Additionally, unless the path to your env is absolute, your package is going to look for the env relative to the executables location, not where it was compiled from

Here are the command lists when working with the dart cmd-line tools and global packages:
Make a package's executables globally available:
dart pub global activate <package>

(Additional):
For example, say you want to use webdev to serve your Dart web application from the command line.
$ dart pub global activate webdev
$ webdev serve

(Additional):
Activating a package
dart pub global activate [--noexecutables] [--executable=<name>] [--overwrite] <package> [version-constraint]

If this doesn't work, you might need to set up your path.
(Additional):
Activating a package on your local machine
$ dart pub global activate --source path <path>


Use activate --source path  to activate a package on your local
machine. The following example activates the stopwatch package from
the ~/dart directory:

$ dart pub global activate --source path ~/dart/stopwatch

Remove a previously activated package.
dart pub global deactivate <package>

List globally activated packages.
dart pub global list

Run an executable from a globally activated package.
dart pub global run

(Additional):
Running a script using dart pub global run
$ dart pub global run <package>:<executable> [args...]

source: VS Code IDE-generated output from dart pub global -h, and for more info: dart pub global
Useful information about dart pub add <package> command:

By default, dart pub add uses the latest stable version of the package
from the pub.dev site that is compatible with your SDK constraints and
dependencies. For example, if 0.13.3 is the latest stable version of
the http package, then dart pub add http adds http: ^0.13.3 under
dependencies in your pubspec.yaml. source: dart pub add

What I performed:
PS C:\path_to_my_dart_cli_project\my_dart_cli_project>flutter pub add dotenv

I hope someone validates this if it is really necessary since we're dealing with a global setup since I have no deep experience with using Dart cmd-line tools.
dart pub global activate dotenv
dart pub global run dotenv:new  # create a .env file and add it to .gitignore
dart pub global run dotenv      # load the file and print only the file environment variables to stdout

I've added some value inside the .env file, which is ENV_DATA=FIRST_VALUE.
then, I got this output:
{ENV_DATA: FIRST_VALUE}

Surprisingly, inside my test\my_dart_cli_project.dart file, I did this:
import 'dart:io';

// import 'package:dotenv/dotenv.dart';

void main() {
  // var env = DotEnv(includePlatformEnvironment: true)..load();

  // p('read all vars? ${env.isEveryDefined(['foo', 'baz'])}');

  // p('foo=${env['foo']}');
  // p('baz=${env['baz']}');
  // p('your home directory is: ${env['HOME']}');

  // env.clear();
  // p('cleared!');

  // p('env has key foo? ${env.isDefined('foo')}');
  // p('env has key baz? ${env.isDefined('baz')}');
  // p('your home directory is still: ${env['HOME']}');
}

// p(String msg) => stdout.writeln(msg);

I am still getting the output {ENV_DATA: FIRST_VALUE}, so I will leave it to you to customize it based on your use case.
